# How to localize the axis number labels for the Shinobi iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, localization, nsnumberformatter, shinobi

The numbers for the axis labels are not getting localized as expected.  When I change the region setting to something like Netherlands the numbers still show with US region formatting.  The period is used as a decimal separator and a comma is used to separate the thousands.  How do I force Shinobi to use a NSNumberFormatter for the tick mark labels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SChartAxis` objects have a property called `labelFormatter`, which is of type `SChartTickLabelFormatter`. This object is used to represent formatters for axes of both number and datetime types. You can set the properties on the `formatter` property of the `labelFormatter` to configure the labels appropriately.

The `numberFormatter` and `dateFormatter` properties allow access to pre-casted versions of the `formatter` property:

For example, on a `SChartNumberAxis` you could use the following line to use the textual form of the numbers (e.g. 'five' instead of '5'):

```
[_chart.xAxis.labelFormatter.numberFormatter
                                 setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterSpellOutStyle];
```

If you want to set the format on a `SChartDateAxis` instead of an `SChartNumberAxis` then use `labelFormatter.dateFormatter` to return a `NSDateFormatter` which you can configure how you wish.

Answer (score 0):

To localize dates use:

```
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"yourLocale"];
[_chart.xAxis.labelFormatter.dateFormatter setLocale:locale];
```